# How to pass a param from one view to another in Ruby on Rails, using POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like this should be an easy thing to figure out, but I'm stumped.

I have a value in a Project's instance variable called ID. I want to pass that value to a new Photos page to associate each photo that is created with that specific project, but I don't want the Project's ID to show up in the visible query string.

I've tried using link_to and button_to, but (I suspect) since I'm using "resources :photos" in my routes, all of the requests that come to photo#new are being interpreted as GET instead of POST.

Helllllllllllllllp!

Thanks to anyone that can give me some insight, I'v been killing myself over this for the past hour or two already.

--Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this in Rails is to create a route that matches urls like this: `/projects/4/photos/new`. Doing something else is up to you, but Rails makes it really easy to do stuff like this. See more on [routes in Rails 3](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/).

Your entry in `routes.rb` should look something like this:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :photos
end
```

Then in `app/controllers/photos_controller.rb` you'd have this for the "New Photo" form page:

```
def new
  @project = Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
end
```

and this for the action that the form in `app/views/photos/new.html.erb` submits to:

```
def create
  @project = Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
  @photo = @project.photos.create(params[:photo])
end
```

Of course you'll want to have error handling and validation in here, but this is the gist of it. And remember, use `GET` for idempotent (non state-changing) actions (e.g. `GET /projects/4/photos`), `POST` for creating a new thing (e.g. `POST /projects/4/photos`), and `PUT` for updating an existing thing (e.g. `PUT /projects/4/photos/8`).

Comment: Thanks Brian. I was trying to figure out how to do this via POST though, because I didn't want the user to be able to easily edit the address bar and end up in another project. I guess there's no way to do that. Thanks again!

Comment: You can do it that way using a hidden `<input>`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Is there another reason for not wanting to allow them to edit the URL than for access control? Because you should be checking that in the controller. If you don't want them to know the id then you can generate an opaque, random identifier (e.g. q8jfa2) for each project. Either way, a determined user can edit either the URL or the DOM to change the project, so make sure you check what you need to on the server.

Comment: Sure, I got it. Do you have any suggestions on how to restrict access to the creation of new Photos to a user that is associated with a specific Project? I'm using Devise/CanCan if that helps...

Comment: It looks like the [README for cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is pretty clear about how to restrict access in the controller. You might also want to read the [wiki page on defining abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities).